# Screwdriver to open Macbook 15" / 2017

Tags: macbook, macbook-pro

What is the exact model of the screwdriver to open the Macbook Pro 15" from 2017 ? I tried some but none worked.

Comment: I suspect ifixit can both hook you up, and have the appropriate tools

Comment: https://www.powerbookmedic.com/manual.php?id=246#tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a P5 Pentalobe screwdriver.

[image: screw]

[image: pentalobe]